Variance of averaged samples from a Gaussian distribution
Let $X = N(\mu,\sigma^2)$
Let $y_n$ is the $n^{th}$ sample drawn from $X$.
Let $Z_n = \frac{\Sigma_{i = 1}^{i = n}y_n}{n}$ .
What is the variance of $Z_n$.
My try:
$A = P_1 + P_2$ with $P_i = N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$
$A = N(\mu_1 + \mu_2,\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)$
If $B = aP$ with $P = N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $B = N(a\mu,a \sigma^2)$.
Now $Z_n = N(\frac{n}{n}\mu,\frac{n}{n}\sigma^2) = N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.
Is this right?
Actually I am studying a (averaging) Kalman filter applied to a static state. I am trying to understand how Kalman filter is smoothing the data when data is sampled from a Gaussian dist. My understanding is that Kalman filter reduces the variance of input measurements $X = N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. How to prove that Kalman filter improves accuracy (reduces the variance) of measurements. What is the correct distribution for $Z_n$.

You've got one of the properties of variance wrong. Namely, if $B=aP$, with $Var[P]=\sigma^2$, then $Var[B]=a^2 \sigma^2$.

Your discourse on the variance is not correct.
Consider the following chain of calculations:
$$
Var[Z_n] = Var\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_n}{n}\right] 
\underset{\text{by the property of variance}}{=}\frac{1}{n^2} Var\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_n\right]
\underset{\text{using the fact that } y_i \text{ are i.i.d.}}{=} \\ 
\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}Var[y_n] = 
\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}1=
\frac{\sigma^2}{n^2} \cdot n = 
\frac{\sigma^2}{n}
$$
Hence, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, the variance of $Z_n$ drops, hence the precision grows.
